# I am losing mass even tho, I've been consistent with my training from time I started gym

Tags: bodybuilding

I just started bodybuilding about two to three weeks ago and I feel like I was gaining some muscle. Now it seems I'm back to square one. It's not like I gained a lot, but what I did gain, I've lost. Why is this happening when I am keeping up with my routine?

Comment: Bodybuilding is a sport of patience. That being said, we can't give proper advice without knowing how you train, how much you eat and if you rest enough.

Comment: I don't feel this is a bad question and should be downvoted. This is a valid question for those entering the sport.

Comment: Eat more, sleep more, lift more. If none of that works, go back in time and have better parents

Answer (score 14):

Bodybuilding is a long term endeavor, two to three weeks is **nothing** in the world of bodybuilding. If you'd said **two to three years**, then it would be a different matter.

Whatever you're doing, carry on doing it for at least 6 months, then see where you are with it.

That being said, if you want to gain muscle (which I assume is what you mean by bodybuilding) check your diet and recovery, if either of those aren't up to par, then it'll stifle your gains.

Comment: This. Well said.

Comment: Yep. I don't think it's realistic to look for results you can see in a mirror for about six months of effective training and a good diet. Somewhere around two years and you can really look like a different person. An old coach likened it to filling up a bathtub, one teaspoon at a time. It just takes time.

Comment: @EricKaufman Fair point. I say 6 months because in my experience it takes something like that for someone who's new to weightlifting / bodybuilding to get comfortable with the movements and start to increase the weight. Also, I did kind of assume the the OP was new to training completely, and newbie gains tend to show pretty quickly, then slow to a crawl.

Answer (score 2):

Its a long journey. For natural lifter, being very strong and muscular takes a good couple of years.

Since you are a new lifter progressive overload works fine for a few months, say 6 months. Then you can change program and still continue adding weights.

The last but not least, if you are eating too much it may cause belly fat that changes your appearence.